# how to use parameter in viewmodel ins xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

Im trying to pass parameter to viewmodel in Xamarin.Forms.But Also I want to use it while loading the page ,to call a rest service with that parameter.But In load event parameter is null always.(I can see that parameter if I bind it to a label or etc...)
How can I make it work properly and use that parameter inside the load event of viewmodel? Any help is appreciated,thanks

> here is the button click event and navigate to Samplepage.

```
 private void OntaptedBildirimItem(string param)
    {
      this._navigationService.NavigateTo(nameof(Views.SamplePage), param);
    }
```

> this is the Sample Page Viewmodel

```
      private string _id;
    public string id
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }
        set
        {
            Set(() => id, ref _id, value);
        }
    }    
public SamplePageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService)
    {
        this._navigationService = navigationService;
        this.Title = "Sample Page=" + id; // here the id is always null,but if I use it to bind a label in xaml ,it has a value.
    }
```

> This is the SamplePage Code

```
     public SamplePage(string parameter)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var viewModel = this.BindingContext as ViewModels.SamplePageViewModel;
        if(viewModel != null && parameter != null)
        {
            viewModel.bildirimid = parameter;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need see NavigationService .

You should add bindingContext in NavigationService not in SamplePage.

In [This Sample](https://github.com/jsuarezruiz/xamarin-forms-netflix-sample) uses NavigationService with a parameter and a better NavigationService structure. You should see it.

Send feedback please.

Comment: This sample is a copy from the Microsoft example and is still not using the parameter object its simply accepting it.

Answer (score 4):

Thx for this  Miguel ,this helps me a lot ,I can do what I want by this approach .You can send parameter while navigating a page in xamarin.forms like this

> `_navigationService.NavigateToAsync<SamplePageViewModel>("Your_parameter");`
>   and you can get that parameter in that page's viewmodel like this

```
 public override async Task InitializeAsync(object yourparameter)
        {
            // use yourparameter as you wish
        }
```

Comment: Yes, this structure is very good.I always use  .You can send parameter between viewmodels  .I'm glad you helped.